MySQL: Timestamp gaps including range bounds
Say, we have a table where messages coming from different devices are stored with arrival timestamps. Let the columns be:

ID (PRIMARY KEY)
DeviceID (INT)
Arrival (TIMESTAMP)
Data (other columns)

Now we need to know what devices and when (from/to) didn’t send any messages for more than N days during a specified period. For example device 1 first arrived on Jan 3, worked till Jan 15 (there were messages), then was turned off until Jan 20, worked till Jan 25 (messages again) and then didn’t send anything until February.
Now, suppose we want the report for January and devices that didn’t work for more than 2 days. Then we should get 3 records for device 1 with the following ranges:

Jan 1 — Jan 3
Jan 15 — Jan 20
Jan 25 — Jan 31
(time parts stripped for simplicity).

If what happened before the first and after the last message in the range didn’t matter, the solution would be pretty straightforward with LEAD() function: selecting cases where current and next messages have their arrival time differences more than the specified amount. But the range bounds might not be in the table but should be treated as possible gap start and/or gap end times if applicable.
What is the best way to do so? (Table has hundreds of messages per second, so effectiveness is also welcome.)
UPD. Added a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/3GRvKcwI It’s quite difficult to produce enough data to play with, so the explanation should have been just enough. Anyway, a few rows there to show what data is about.
For N days being equal to 3 and for date range being 2024-01-01 00:00:00 to 2024-01-09 23:59:59, and for that particular dataset the query should return:
DeviceID | From                | To
123      | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-01-05 19:23:18
123      | 2024-01-06 03:46:11 | 2024-01-09 23:59:59
125      | 2024-01-02 21:16:25 | 2024-01-08 19:23:18
321      | 2024-01-01 07:01:04 | 2024-01-07 05:06:54
542      | 2024-01-05 09:06:31 | 2024-01-09 23:59:59

’cause during the period from Jan 1 to Jan 9 device 123 didn’t send messages for longer than 3 days twice, other devices once each. My problem is that gaps may start and/or end not only with timestamps from the table but also with boundaries of the date range used for the report, otherwise it would be a simple LEAD()-based query.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go here and construct a fiddle with some sample data and the result(s) you would like from that data - as it stands, I don't understand what it is, exactly, you are looking for?

See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

@Vérace Sample data would contain quite a lot of rows and sharing real data is not possible, so I tried to construct as small dataset as possible to demonstrate what is needed. Edited the post accordingly.

Seems to me that we only need ID (PRIMARY KEY), DeviceID (INT) & Arrival (TIMESTAMP) - the data can be dummy - payload TEXT NOT NULL-payload1, 2, 3...`! It's those first 3 fields that are important for your question - we don't require any data AFAICS.

@Vérace Yes, the Data field (just as I stated in the question) is there just for completeness (to avoid solutions that won’t work if there’re other fields). That is obviously why I don’t use it anywhere later in the explanation of my problem.

This proved trickier than I thought! I learnt a lot from tracking down the answer to this (+1) (all of the code is available on the fiddle here)!
The first thing I did was slightly change the DDL as follows:
CREATE TABLE message 
(
  ID        BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Arrival   TIMESTAMP           NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  device_id INT(10)    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  dat       TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- data is a MySQL reserved word
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


data is a reserved word (same as LAG, LEAD and even LEADING - bit of head-scratching there!).

I also renamed the table message (no "s") - tables are sets and therefore singular - at least as far as I'm concerned - this way I never have to ask myself if the table's name is "thing" or "things"... YMMV!


I also took the INDEX creation out of the table create statement proper, since I like giving my indexes names - as follows.
CREATE UNIQE INDEX dev_id_arr_ix         
ON message (device_id, arrival);

I created a single UNIQUE INDEX with device_id and arrival - that could even be your natural PRIMARY KEY key instead of the surrogate id. Having these two fields as the PK would mean that you couldn't add dupes to your data. You may wish to see if this works better than your surrogate key.
Then, I INSERTed the records - I added one for testing.
INSERT INTO message (arrival, device_id, dat) VALUES
  
-- > 3 days from 01-01 00:00  
('2024-01-05 19:23:18', 123,  48),   -- 2 in resultset for did = 123
('2024-01-06 03:46:11', 123,  19),

  
('2024-01-01 15:03:37', 125,  8),   -- 1 in resultset for did = 125
('2024-01-02 21:16:25', 125,  46),
--  > 3 days between above and below 
('2024-01-08 19:23:18', 125, 123),

-- below added for testing.
  
--  > 3 days before    
('2024-01-05 20:05:45', 222,  33),  -- 2 in resultset for did = 222
-- > 3 days after

  
('2024-01-01 07:01:04', 321,  51),  -- 1 in resultset for did = 321
-- > 3 days between above and below
('2024-01-04 11:18:23', 321,  42),
('2024-01-07 05:06:54', 321, 108),

  
('2024-01-01 00:01:02', 542,  15),   -- 1 in resultset for did = 542
('2024-01-01 12:02:51', 542,  27),
('2024-01-02 14:12:42', 542,  34),
('2024-01-03 08:03:19', 542,  63),
('2024-01-05 09:06:31', 542,  53);
-- 3 days between last record and 01-09 23:59:59

-- Therefore, we expect 7 records in our result set!

I organised the records by device_id and by arrival - this helps greatly with the analysis - it' good to get an "eyeball" view of your data and have it in your mind when coding - obviously for a large table, you'd take a subset, but going through that subset manually really gives the problem form - again, at least for me!
After much messing (vow to self, never try to programme on a bus using your tablet again - errors just come in thick and fast!), I came up with the following which I think solves your issue. I'll go through the steps (although for an insight into all of the rabbit-holes I went down, see here - I'm very rusty when it comes to MySQL!).
SELECT
  id,
  
  DATE_FORMAT
  (
    LAG(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
      OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY arrival), '%Y-%m-%d %H'
  ) AS lagging ,

  CASE
    WHEN
      timestampdiff
      (
        SECOND,
        LAG(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
        OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY arrival),
        arrival
      ) > 259200 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS lg3,
  
  DATE_FORMAT(arrival,'%Y-%m-%d %H') AS arr,

  CASE
    WHEN
      TIMESTAMPDIFF
      (
        SECOND,
        arrival,
        LEAD(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-09 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
        OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY arrival)
      ) > 259200 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS ld3,

  DATE_FORMAT
  (
    LEAD(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-09 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
      OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY arrival), '%Y-%m-%d %H'
  ) as "leading",

  device_id AS did

FROM message
ORDER BY device_id, arrival;

Result:
id  lagging       lg3   arr          ld3    leading         did
1   2024-01-01 00   1   2024-01-05 19   0   2024-01-06 03   123
2   2024-01-05 19   0   2024-01-06 03   1   2024-01-09 23   123
3   2024-01-01 00   0   2024-01-01 15   0   2024-01-02 21   125
4   2024-01-01 15   0   2024-01-02 21   1   2024-01-08 19   125
5   2024-01-02 21   1   2024-01-08 19   0   2024-01-09 23   125
6   2024-01-01 00   1   2024-01-05 20   1   2024-01-09 23   222
7   2024-01-01 00   0   2024-01-01 07   1   2024-01-04 11   321
8   2024-01-01 07   1   2024-01-04 11   0   2024-01-07 05   321
9   2024-01-04 11   0   2024-01-07 05   0   2024-01-09 23   321
10  2024-01-01 00   0   2024-01-01 00   0   2024-01-01 12   542
11  2024-01-01 00   0   2024-01-01 12   0   2024-01-02 14   542
12  2024-01-01 12   0   2024-01-02 14   0   2024-01-03 08   542
13  2024-01-02 14   0   2024-01-03 08   0   2024-01-05 09   542
14  2024-01-03 08   0   2024-01-05 09   1   2024-01-09 23   542

So, we get the date (lagging) behind any of the first arrival dates for any of the devices as 2024-01-01 00:00:00 - minutes and seconds not visible. The reason I used DATE_FORMAT was so I could read everthing across 1 line on my screen - I find that helps).
If I didn't have the LAG(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) code, these values would have been NULL and not very useful.
We do the same for leading, using the timestamp 2024-01-09 23:59:59 as the default, since it would be NULL for (in the case of the LEAD() function) the last record of a given window (PARTITION BY device_id).
The CASE statement is used to pick out those records which are more than 3 days before or after the arrival record being examined - this gives us our records of interest.
So, the records of interest are those with lg3 or ld3 = 1. We refine our query (some steps skipped - again, see the fiddle):
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT
  id,
  device_id AS did,  
  
  LAG(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
    OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY arrival) AS tlag,  

  arrival,

  
  CASE
    WHEN
      timestampdiff
      (
        SECOND,
        LAG(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
          OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY arrival),
        arrival
      ) > 259200 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS lg3,
  
  CASE
    WHEN
      TIMESTAMPDIFF
      (
        SECOND,
        arrival,
        LEAD(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-09 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
          OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY arrival)
      ) > 259200 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
  END AS ld3,

  LEAD(arrival, 1, STR_TO_DATE('2024-01-09 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
    OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY arrival) AS tlead
  
FROM message
ORDER BY device_id, arrival
)
SELECT 
  did AS dev_id,
  tlag AS "Time from", arrival, -- (- INTERVAL 1 SECOND AS "Time to"),
  '> 3 day gap' AS "problem"
FROM cte
WHERE lg3 = 1
-- ORDER BY did, arrival
UNION 
SELECT 
  did,
  arrival, tlead, '> 3 day gap'
FROM cte
WHERE ld3 = 1
ORDER BY 
  dev_id, "Time from";

Result:
dev_id  Time from   arrival     problem
123     2024-01-01 00:00:00     2024-01-05 19:23:18     > 3 day gap
123     2024-01-06 03:46:11     2024-01-09 23:59:59     > 3 day gap
125     2024-01-02 21:16:25     2024-01-08 19:23:18     > 3 day gap
222     2024-01-01 00:00:00     2024-01-05 20:05:45     > 3 day gap
222     2024-01-05 20:05:45     2024-01-09 23:59:59     > 3 day gap
321     2024-01-01 07:01:04     2024-01-04 11:18:23     > 3 day gap
542     2024-01-05 09:06:31     2024-01-09 23:59:59     > 3 day gap

So, we see that we indeed have 7 records - which we counted at the INSERTion of the records stage! We need UNION as opposed to UNION ALL - play around and check out why!
There is one fly in the ointment - where I have -- (- INTERVAL 1 SECOND AS "Time to") at the end - you'll have to do this yourself - otherwise, you'll have overlapping intervals. This could be solved trivially with PostgreSQL's RANGE and MULTIRANGE types (see here and here) - but, I think it shouldn't be too difficult and I'm tired and going to bed!
